# how to make mule event generator as multi threaded in dev kit?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I am developing a custom connector for generating Mule events using anypoint dev kit. So I am using the `@Source` annotation above the method.

I want to make it multithreaded. For example, for one polling i want to start 5 threads. These 5 threads would process and generate events pushed out parallel.

I would like to make the thread-count configurable.

Is there any related configuration available on mule side?